# To find the last digit of the number $4^{7^5}$?

Tags: proof-verification, modular-arithmetic

To find the last digit of the number $4^{7^5}$, I use the following method.

first, we know $4\equiv_{10}4,4^2\equiv_{10}6,4^3\equiv_{10}4,...,4^{2n}\equiv_{10}6,4^{2n+1}\equiv_{10}4$

Then$7^1\equiv_21,7^2\equiv_21,7^3\equiv_21,...,7^5\equiv_21$

Therefore, $4^{7^5}\equiv4^{2k+1}\equiv_{10}4$.(because of the remainder 1)

and if to find the last digit of $4^{8^3}$ instead, the answer will be 6. Because $8^n\equiv_20,n\in \mathbb{N^+}$ so $8^n=2k,k\in\mathbb{N^+}$. From above, $4^{2k}\equiv_{10}6$

Is my method correct?

Comment: Yes, that is a good solution.

Comment: It's fine! But you may simply argue that $7^5$ is odd and $8^3$ is even.

Answer (score 1):

$$4^{7^5}=4\cdot\left(4^2\right)^{\frac{7^5-1}{2}}\equiv4\cdot6(\mod10)\equiv4(\mod10)$$

Comment: Use \pmod instead.

Comment: @Asaf Karagila I tried. It quits not good: $\equiv(\pmod10)$

Comment: Maybe it's time to learn $\rm\LaTeX$. $\equiv\pmod{10}$.

Comment: @Asaf Karagila Fix please my post. I want to see, what  you mean. Thank you!

Comment: @Michael Rozenberg: ¡Ingenious!

Answer (score 1):

Your method is correct. Another way is to consider the easy fact that

$$2^{4n+k}= \begin{cases}2\pmod {10}\text{ for}\space k=1\\4\pmod {10}\text{ for}\space k=2\\8\pmod {10}\text{ for}\space k=3\\6\pmod {10}\text{ for}\space k=0\end{cases}$$ and the calculation $$7^5=16807$$ Then $$4^{7^{5}}=2^{33614}=2^{33612+2}=4\pmod{10}$$